# Can google analytics _setDomainName be used to log events to a different subdomain?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have various subdomains and am using different google analytics profiles to track each one.  However, I have come to the scenario where I would like to log pageviews from one subdomain to a different subdomain so they will show up together in a specific profile.  Can _setDomainName be used this way (to log to a different domain than the actual one a user is on?) If so can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not how _setDomainName works. _setDomainName is used when storing the first party cookies Google Analytics uses. It MUST follow the same rules for domains used when setting cookies.

Read Wiki's [HTTP Cookie's Attribute Section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
or [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)

There are official docs with instructions to implement GA on several domains.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: Makes sense.  Looks like we'll need to re-evaluate. Thanks.